# How to convert a Ballerina record array into a map?

Tags: ballerina

I have the following record array(`Foo[]`) and I want to convert it into a map(`map<Foo>`).
It's possible to create a map from a record array as shown below, but is there a better way to do this?

```
import ballerina/io;

type Foo record {|
    readonly int id;
    string text;
|};

public function main() {
    map<Foo> fooMap = {};
    Foo[] fooArray = [
        {id: 1, text: "one"},
        {id: 2, text: "two"},
        {id: 42, text: "forty-two"}
    ];

    foreach Foo f in fooArray {
        fooMap[f.id.toString()] = f;
    }
    io:println(fooMap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use query expression to create a map from a record array.

```
import ballerina/io;

type Foo record {|
    readonly int id;
    string text;
|};

public function main() {
    Foo[] fooArray = [
        {id: 1, text: "one"},
        {id: 2, text: "two"},
        {id: 42, text: "forty-two"}
    ];

    map<Foo> fooMap = map from Foo f in fooArray select [f.id.toString(), f];
    io:println(fooMap);
}
```